# Starting Dropbox behind a proxy server

Tags: 14.04, proxy, dropbox

There are a few posts here that claim to solve the problem I am having but they do unfortunately not work.

I have managed to install dropbox through the proxy server using the command

```
sudo https_proxy="http://username:password@your_proxy:proxy_port" dropbox start -i
```

and Dropbox seemed to download and install properly.

Now however when I want to start dropbox i get the following screen:

[image]

Any advice on starting Dropbox through a proxy server?

Comment: you are using Unity, Gnome or something else?

Comment: This awkward, but I am not sure. Its the default Ubuntu GUI, I think Unity??

Comment: You can start dropbox itself by a similar command. I guess you just need to cut off the "start -i". If this doesn't work you can set the proxy settings as an environment variable: "export https_proxy="http://username:password@your_proxy:proxy_port". Afterwards you need to start dropbox in the same terminal (the variable belongs only to this terminal and needs to be set again after closing). Another way is to set the proxy globally in the desktop environment. Then you will be able to start dropbox by gui. Normally you find these options in the network section (in Unity the Network Manager?)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, in case someone else is struggling with this issue, I'm gonna post a step by step procedure on how one can go about setting their proxy on dropbox. Right click Dropbox from the system tray, and click on Preference > proxy, see below for step-by-step screenshots:

[image: Right click to see dropbox preference]
[image: preference]

Click on "proxy":

[image: proxy]

set your proxy accordingly:

[image: set your proxy]

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the dropbox icon in the systray and manually configure the proxy from the preferences.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however, I believe the system tray is no longer integrated into the unity dash on newer versions of Ubuntu. There is a ppa that users can install to allow the option to enable the system tray but unfortunately, our newer versions don't show items in the system tray unless the application is configured to have an "appindicator" or indicator type applet show directly on the dash bar. From what the OP has said to other users, it appears that dropbox is not configured this way so the icon no longer shows up.